# I am attempting to add a second SSD to my Alienware M15 i7 and it is not working as expected

Tags: ssd

I am attempting to add a second SSD to my Alienware M15 i7.

I have a new 4 TB Crucial P3 Plus SSD NVMe (SSD) which is well seated in the available PCI slot.

The SSD is visible in my up to date BIOS.

The SSD is neither visible in Disk Manager nor Device Manager.

Dell tech support stated the Alienware M15 can ONLY be upgraded to 1 TB.

Would someone help me configure my Alienware M15 to recognize the new 4TB SSD?

Comment: When you say the device is installed in a PCI slot do you actually mean a M.2 NVMe slot? Are you positive it’s a PCIe NVMe slot? [Edit] your question to clarify this fact.

Comment: Please describe in greater detail what exactly “SSD is visible in BIOS” means. Where are you seeing what exactly? // Maybe try with a Live Linux and see whether it works with that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the
[Crucial Alienware M15 upgrades](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/alienware/alienware-m15),
PCIe Gen4 NVMe M.2 SSD can go up to 4 TB, so Dell tech support might
be wrong, or your disk is unsuitable or perhaps it's badly installed.
However, there are several M15 models, so I might have looked at the
wrong one.

I suggest to run the
[Crucial system scanner](https://www.crucial.com/store/systemscanner)
to analyze your system and suggest updates.
If a larger SSD is suggested, make sure that you know how to install
the disk.